# How to extract text in between <br> python

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have extracted some div through "inspect elements" from link http://www.sanfoundry.com/c-programming-questions-answers-variable-names-1/ . In the **div** there is <**p**> and in the <**p**> there is some text which is break line by <**br**> and i am trying to extract those text so that i can place in array or db one by one.I am stuck in extracting the require text which is before and after <**br**>.

```
<div class="entry-content" style="visibility: visible; opacity: 1;">
 <div style="text-align:justify">
This section on C interview <span id="IL_AD1" class="IL_AD">questions and answers</span> focuses on “Variable Names”. One shall practice these <span id="IL_AD5" class="IL_AD">interview questions</span> to improve their C programming skills needed for various interviews (campus interviews, walkin interviews, company interviews), placements, entrance exams and other competitive exams. These questions can be attempted by anyone focusing on learning C Programming language. They can be a beginner, fresher, engineering graduate or an experienced IT professional. Our C Interview questions come with detailed explanation of the <span id="IL_AD2" class="IL_AD">answers</span> which helps in better understanding of C <span id="IL_AD3" class="IL_AD">concepts</span>.<p></p>
<p>Here is a listing of C interview questions on “Variable Names” along with answers, explanations and/or solutions:
</p></div>
<p>1. C99 standard guarantees uniqueness of ____ characters for internal names.<br>
a) 31<br>
b) 63<br>
c) 12<br>
d) 14</p>
<span class="collapseomatic" id="id5489" tabindex="0" title="View Answer">View Answer</span><div id="target-id5489" class="collapseomatic_content " style="display: none;">Answer:b<br>
Explanation:ISO C99 compiler may consider only first 63 characters for internal.<br>
</div>
<p>2. C99 standard guarantess uniqueness of _____ characters for external names.<br>
a) 31<br>
b) 6<br>
c) 12<br>
d) 14</p>
<span class="collapseomatic " id="id7970" tabindex="0" title="View Answer">View Answer</span><div id="target-id7970" class="collapseomatic_content " style="display: none;">Answer:a<br>
Explanation:ISO C99 compiler may consider only first 31 characters for external<br>
variables having 31 characters due to which it may not be unique.<br>
</div>
<p>3. Which of the following is not a valid variable name declaration?<br>
a) int __a3;<br>
b) int __3a;<br>
c) int __A3;<br>
d) None of the mentioned</p>
<span class="collapseomatic " id="id5714" tabindex="0" title="View Answer">View Answer</span><div id="target-id5714" class="collapseomatic_content " style="display: none;">Answer:d<br>
Explanation:None.<br>
</div>
<p>4. Which of the following is not a valid variable name declaration?<br>
a) int _a3;<br>
b) int a_3;<br>
c) int 3_a;<br>
d) int _3a</p>
```

So how shell i separately get **"C99 standard guarantees uniqueness of ____ characters for internal"** ,**"31","63","12","14", "C99 standard guarantess uniqueness of _____ characters for external" and "31","6","12","14"** and so on......

Along with this i also do not need bullet numbering and alphabetically

code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmls, 'html.parser')
h4s = soup.find_all('p')
for h4 in h4s:
    for text in h4.find_next_siblings('br'):
        print(text.strip())
```

Any idea where i am wrong ?

Comment: Paste the html with proper closing tag. and how do you want your output?

Comment: actually i am using this link, And wants to get question separate , each option separate

Comment: link: http://www.sanfoundry.com/c-programming-questions-answers-variable-names-1/

Comment: I don't want to visit the link and do the whole work for you.

Comment: but data from inspect elements are too much how can i copy and paste here. It is 180000000 but here i can place only 300000 charaters.

Comment: i have paste the div and in the div there is <p> and in <p> there is <br> from where i want to extract text...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `CSS Selector` in this case- `soup.select('div.entry-content p')` will select a div with class(see `.`) name `entry-content` and all `p` inside that div. I assumed there is only one `div` with that class name.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = """<div class="entry-content" style="visibility: visible; opacity: 1;">
 <div style="text-align:justify">
This section on C interview <span id="IL_AD1" class="IL_AD">questions and answers</span> focuses on “Variable Names”. One shall practice these <span id="IL_AD5" class="IL_AD">interview questions</span> to improve their C programming skills needed for various interviews (campus interviews, walkin interviews, company interviews), placements, entrance exams and other competitive exams. These questions can be attempted by anyone focusing on learning C Programming language. They can be a beginner, fresher, engineering graduate or an experienced IT professional. Our C Interview questions come with detailed explanation of the <span id="IL_AD2" class="IL_AD">answers</span> which helps in better understanding of C <span id="IL_AD3" class="IL_AD">concepts</span>.<p></p>
<p>Here is a listing of C interview questions on “Variable Names” along with answers, explanations and/or solutions:
</p></div>
<p>1. C99 standard guarantees uniqueness of ____ characters for internal names.<br>
a) 31<br>
b) 63<br>
c) 12<br>
d) 14</p>
<span class="collapseomatic" id="id5489" tabindex="0" title="View Answer">View Answer</span><div id="target-id5489" class="collapseomatic_content " style="display: none;">Answer:b<br>
Explanation:ISO C99 compiler may consider only first 63 characters for internal.<br>
</div>
<p>2. C99 standard guarantess uniqueness of _____ characters for external names.<br>
a) 31<br>
b) 6<br>
c) 12<br>
d) 14</p>
<span class="collapseomatic " id="id7970" tabindex="0" title="View Answer">View Answer</span><div id="target-id7970" class="collapseomatic_content " style="display: none;">Answer:a<br>
Explanation:ISO C99 compiler may consider only first 31 characters for external<br>
variables having 31 characters due to which it may not be unique.<br>
</div>
<p>3. Which of the following is not a valid variable name declaration?<br>
a) int __a3;<br>
b) int __3a;<br>
c) int __A3;<br>
d) None of the mentioned</p>
<span class="collapseomatic " id="id5714" tabindex="0" title="View Answer">View Answer</span><div id="target-id5714" class="collapseomatic_content " style="display: none;">Answer:d<br>
Explanation:None.<br>
</div>
<p>4. Which of the following is not a valid variable name declaration?<br>
a) int _a3;<br>
b) int a_3;<br>
c) int 3_a;<br>
d) int _3a</p>"""

soup = bs(html,'html.parser')

p = soup.select('div.entry-content p')
for i in p[2:]:
    print i.text.encode('utf-8')
    print '\n'*3 # just print three newlines
```

Output-

```
1. C99 standard guarantees uniqueness of ____ characters for internal names.
a) 31
b) 63
c) 12
d) 14




2. C99 standard guarantess uniqueness of _____ characters for external names.
a) 31
b) 6
c) 12
d) 14




3. Which of the following is not a valid variable name declaration?
a) int __a3;
b) int __3a;
c) int __A3;
d) None of the mentioned




4. Which of the following is not a valid variable name declaration?
a) int _a3;
b) int a_3;
c) int 3_a;
d) int _3a
```